# ODBC why platform is 32/64

Tags: odbc, 64-bit

Hello am having an small issue with my ODBC when i create user DNS it says on platform 32/64 bit instead of just 64 bit. I tired looking online and i still don't know what to do all my properties are correct? Also I don't get this issue when i try to Create a system DNS.

Comment: Which ODBC driver are you using? Also, it looks like you are talking about Windows' ODBC Administrator. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is and what do you mean by drive do you mean like adaptive server enterprise ?

Comment: when i try to use adaptive server enterprise it actually closes the app so am trying to use sql server first

Answer (score 0):

"32/64-bit" in the "Platform" column indicates that the ODBC Administrator believes that both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the ODBC driver are available to that User DSN. User DSNs are common to both 64-bit and 32-bit applications.

The "Platform" column does not appear in the "System DSN" tab because System DSNs are maintained separately via filesystem/registry virtualization in the 32-bit subsystem for 64-bit Windows (SysWOW64). The 64-bit ODBC Administrator (System32\odbcad32.exe) will only show 64-bit System DSNs, while the 32-bit ODBC Administrator (SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) will only show 32-bit System DSNs.